# TinyMCE 5.7.0 - Cannot read property 'isTouch' of undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce, tinymce-5

I have a project based on ASP.NET MVC. After upgrading to the latest version of `TinyMCE` from version 4, I get an error message on one is cshtml where it is used:
[image]

In version 4, the `modern` theme was used, which replaced the `silver` theme. However, TinyMCE is initializing from Shared cshtml, could there be a problem? Can you please point me in the right direction? Because I don't have any problem on other cshtml where initialize TinyMCE without shared cshtml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I commented:

```
<script src="~/Content/tinymce4/skins/lightgray/imagetools-created.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/tinymce4/skins/lightgray/imagetools-theme.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/tinymce4/skins/lightgray/imagetools-created.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

then TinyMCE started working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error using a build of tinymce for Angular and for me the issue was that I had neglected to do an

```
npm install
```

after upgrading to a more recent version of tinymce.